# SUMIFS statement with Array Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, sumifs

and Thank you in advance!  I'm trying to sum a column's value in Excel 2013 based on a number of conditions.  The equation I have looks like:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS((SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ),SQLExport!$AN:$AN,{"Review","Completed"},SQLExport!$AY:$AY,D4,SQLExport!$Y:$Y,">="&Snapshot!$B$2,SQLExport!$Y:$Y,"<="&Snapshot!$D$2))
```

In English I want to SUM the values in SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ column based on:

SQLExport!$AN:$AN column has a value of "Review" OR "Completed"

AND SQLExport!$AY:$AY column is equal to D4

AND SQLExport!$Y:$Y column is greater than or equal to the date in Snapshot!$B$2

AND SQLExport!$Y:$Y column is less than or equal to the date in Snapshot!$D$2

Afterwards, I need to be able to divide the SUMIF by the result of another cell. (This shouldn't be an issue, as long as I can get the SUMIF to work.)

The results I get are consistently higher than what I get when doing the math manually.  However, I don't know where the disconnect is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Why the outer `SUM()`? Won't the `=SUMIFS(SumRange, Range1, condition1, range2, condition2,...)` do what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately, without the SUM(), the equation is resulting in an answer Significantly less, than the desired result.  With the SUM(SUMIFS()) the result is 39, with only the SUMIFS() the result is 14. The desired result is 29.  Please advise.

Comment: Your formula looks OK to me - the reason you need SUM is that by using {"Review","Completed"} as one of the criteria an array of two values is returned by SUMIFS, so SUM is used to sum those. Why do you think the result is wrong, how are you calculating 29? If result is 14 without SUM that means that you are getting 14 for the "Review" part (and presumably 25 for "Completed")

Answer (score 0):

Because your conditions are a bit more complex then the usual `SUMIFS` type conditions that one usually sees, consider switching instead to `=SumProduct()`. This would take the form:

```
SumProduct(((SQLExport!$AN:$AN="Review") + (SQLExport!$AN:$AN="Completed")) * (SQLExport!$AY:$AY=D4) * (SQLExport!$Y:$Y >= Snapshot!$B$2) * (SQLExport!$Y:$Y <= Snapshot!$D$2) * (SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ) * 1)
```

Comment: You can't use OR like that in these type of formulas - OR returns a single result TRUE/FALSE not the required array of TRUE/FALSE values - you can simulate "OR" by adding the conditions like `(SQLExport!$AN:$AN="Review")+(SQLExport!$AN:$AN="Completed")`

Comment: I hadn't tried it myself, but you are probably correct. I changed the formula to be more boolean arithmetic-y instead of using OR()

Comment: That expression is resulting in a #VALUE! where the evaluation is showing as SUMPRODUCT({#VALUE!;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0})

Comment: You shouldn't need the *1 at the end, or the * to multiply that range .....and those features will actually result in a #VALUE error if you have any text in column AZ (a header, for example) - with SUMPRODUCT it's better to use a specific range like AZ2:AZ1000.....or replace `*(SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ)*1` with just`,SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ`

Comment: I had a stray ampersand in the formula that was a hold over from the `sum(sumifs())` formula in the question. I would agree with @barryhoudini about using a specific range, unless your data lacks headers, in which case this formula will be just fine (albeit a bit slow). Also the `*1` is superflous in this example, but I always just leave it in case I want to toggle this from a complex `sumifs` to a complex `countifs` by removing the sum range of `(SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ)`

Comment: Okay, I removed the *1 and the current equation looks like the following, after excel kindly offered to fix a typo somewhere in there:  '=SUMPRODUCT((SQLExport!$AN:$AN="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN:$AN="09-Completed")*(SQLExport!$AY:$AY=D4)*(SQLExport!$Y:$Y>=Snapshot!$B$2)*(SQLExport!$Y:$Y<=Snapshot!$D$2),SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ)'   Using the range like AZ2-AZ1000 still gave a #VALUE issue, but the current code results in 75708 as the answer.  A little higher than the 29 I would like.  I am calculating the doing the filtering on the table myself and summing the column accordingly.

Comment: You need an extra set of parentheses around the two conditions that are linked with + (as JNevill's example)

Comment: e.g.  `=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN:$AN="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN:$AN="09-Completed"))*(SQLExport!$AY:$AY=D4)*(SQLExport!$Y‌​:$Y>=Snapshot!$B$2)*(SQLExport!$Y:$Y<=Snapshot!$D$2),SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ)`

Comment: I have no idea how you guys are figuring this out.  Its way above me excelwise.  So Thank you.  I have tried:  `=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN:$AN="08-Customer review") + (SQLExport!$AN:$AN="09-Completed")) * (SQLExport!$AY:$AY=D4) * (SQLExport!$Y:$Y >= Snapshot!$B$2) * (SQLExport!$Y:$Y <= Snapshot!$D$2) * (SQLExport!AZ2:AZ50000) * 1)` and it is giving me a #N/A result.  My table does have headers.  Please advise, I'm at your mercy.

Comment: Barry, your latest formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN:$AN="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN:$AN="09-Completed"))*(SQLExport!$AY:$AY=D4)*(SQLExport!$‌​Y‌​:$Y>=Snapshot!$B$2)*(SQLExport!$Y:$Y<=Snapshot!$D$2),SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ)` is giving me an invalid Array1 result.

Comment: If you have headers I would recommend: `=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN2:$AN10000="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN2:$AN10000="09-Completed"))*(SQLExport!$AY2:$AY10000=D4)*(SQLExport!$‌​‌​Y‌2​:$Y10000>=Snapshot!$B$2)*(SQLExport!$Y2:$Y10000<=Snapshot!$D$2)*SQLExport!$AZ2:$AZ10000)`  The way this works is that each condition statement (the ones with the `=` or `<=` or `>=` returns a true or false, which is just a 1 or 0. Those 1's and 0's get added and multiplied according to the formula for each record, then gets multiplied by whatever is in column AZ. It does this for ea. row and adds results.

Comment: JNevill, that is giving me a flat out invalid formula prompt.  What else can I get you guys that would help?  Current formula is    `=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN2:$AN10000="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN2:$AN10000="09-Completed"))*(SQLExport!$AY2:$AY10000=D4)*‌​(SQLExport!$‌​‌​Y‌2​:$Y10000>=Snapshot!$B$2)*(SQLExport!$Y2:$Y10000<=Snapshot!$D$‌​2)*SQLExport!$AZ:$AZ)`  Please advise!

Comment: Slight correction to your last attempt: `=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN2:$AN10000="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN2:$AN10000="09-Completed"))*(SQLExport!$AY2:$AY10000=D4)*‌​‌​(SQLExport!$‌​‌​Y‌2​:$Y10000>=Snapshot!$B$2)*(SQLExport!$Y2:$Y10000<=Snapshot!$‌​D$‌​2)*SQLExport!$AZ2:$AZ10000)` Note the change to the range in your AZ column. With sumproduct it's imperative that all of your ranges that you are testing and multiplying are of equal length

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN2:$AN100000="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN2:$AN100000="09-Completed"))*(SQLExport!$AY2:$AY100000=D4)*‌​‌​‌​(SQLExport!$‌​‌​Y‌2​:$Y100000>=Snapshot!$B$2)*(SQLExport!$Y2:$Y100000<=Snapshot‌​!$‌​D$‌​2)*SQLExport!$AZ2:$AZ100000)` Still gives me the invalid expression message.

Comment: I hope I didn't stump you guys.  Any ideas as to why this would be an invalid expression?  What can I get you to help the troubleshooting?

Comment: Sometimes problems are caused when you copy formulas - particularly from comments - I copied back one of these formulas and some of the data seems to need re-typing - let me post an answer with a suggested formula - I think copying from an answer might be better....

Answer (score 0):

Try this version with only 9 rows - let's see if we can get that working before you increase the range sizes:

`=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN2:$AN10="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN2:$AN10="09-Completed"))*(SQLExport!$AY2:$AY10=D4)*(SQLExport!$Y2:$Y10>=Snapshot!B2)*(SQLExport!$Y2:$Y10<=Snapshot!D2),SQLExport!$AZ2:$AZ10)`

That's a valid formula for me and remains valid when I copy back to my worksheet

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  `=SUMPRODUCT(((SQLExport!$AN2:$AN99000="08-Customer review")+(SQLExport!$AN2:$AN99000="09-Completed"))*(SQLExport!$AY2:$AY99000=D4)*(SQLExport!$Y2:$Y99000>=Snapshot!B2)*(SQLExport!$Y2:$Y99000<=Snapshot!D2),SQLExport!$AZ2:$AZ99000)` Worked as an expression, but returned 39 as the result.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me - as I said initially there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the SUMIFS formula and that also returns 39 - perhaps that's the correct result and your other calculation method is incorrect? Perhaps you can isolate the problem - what if you use COUNTIFS as per your initial formula but without the sum range - how many rows does that give you?